# VBA hyperlink on all cell when creating a range

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I would like to apply `=HYPERLINK()` function in Excel on the "XYZ" range where each cell is referenced to its counterpart in ABC sheet. Just not sure how to do that as I am a toal noob when it comes to VBA.

```
Sub Calculator()
    Dim instances As Long
    Dim blanks As Long

    ' Prepare for allocation
    Set mainline = ActiveWorkbook
    lastrowABC = Sheets("ABC").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'newprep
    Sheets("Sheet").Cells.Clear
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


    ' Add Formulas to Sheet Tab
    Worksheets("Sheet").Activate
    With Sheets("Sheet")
            .Range("A1") = "XYZ"
            .Range("A2:A" & lastrowABC) = Sheets("ABC").Range("Z2:Z" & lastrowABC).value
```

Comment: Exaclty! but ideally I need it to function like "=Hyperlink('ABC'!Z2)" but applied on the entirety of the range

Comment: I apologize, didn't know the best way to properly phrase it

Answer (score 1):

Just write the `.Formula` directly:

Change

```
.Range("A2:A" & lastrowABC) = Sheets("ABC").Range("Z2:Z" & lastrowABC).value
```

to

```
.Range("A2:A" & lastrowABC).Formula = "='ABC'!Z2"
```

**EDIT**:

If you want an actual hyperlink, then perhaps something like the following:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim lastRowABC As Long
    lastRowABC = Sheets("ABC").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    With Worksheets("Sheet")
        .Range("A1") = "XYZ"

        Dim i As Long
        For i = 2 To lastRowABC
            .Range("A" & i).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""#'ABC'!Z" & i & """, ""ABC!Z" & i & """)"
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: would this create "='ABC' !Z2" as a hyperlink (applied to all cells in range, the thing is that the reference sheet is updated regularly and the row count varies)

Comment: @konsama try it.

Comment: Threw an error, went to debug on that line in VBA editor

Comment: I wrote the code wrong, I applied the function, it worked, but the goal that I would like is when XYZ is filtered it applies that filter to ABC as well

Comment: That's a whole different question. I would go for a `Worksheet_Change` approach.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change